# Logstash/Elasticsearch keep auto-mapping geoip to object instead of geo_point

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have some logs with the following format(I changed the IPs from public to private, but you get the idea):

```
192.168.0.1 [20/Nov/2019:16:09:28 +0000] GET /some_path HTTP/1.1 200 2 2
192.168.0.2  [20/Nov/2019:16:09:28 +0000] GET /some_path HTTP/1.1 200 2 2
```

I then grok these logs using the following pattern:

```
grok { match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:clientip} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{DATA:httpversion} %{NUMBER:response} %{NUMBER:duration}" } }
         geoip { source => "clientip" }
```

On my output section, I have the following code:

```
else  if "host.name" in [host][name]{ #if statement with the hostname
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "mms18-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    user => "admin-user"
    password => "admin-password"
  }

}
```

The problem is that when I go to Kibana the geoip.location is mapped as an object, and I can not use it on a map Dashboard.
Since the index's name changed daily, I can not manually put the correct geoip mapping, since I would have to do it every day.

One solution I thought that partially solves the problem is removing the date from the index in Logstash output, so it has a constant index of "mms18" and then using this on Kibana management console:

```
PUT mms18
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "geoip": {
        "properties": {
          "location": { "type": "geo_point" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this is not ideal since I want to have the option of showing all the indexes with their respectful dates, and then choosing what to delete and what not.
Is there any way that I can achieve the correct mapping while also preserving the indexes with their dates?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) (with a value for index_patterns like "mms-*") that maps geoip as a geo_point.

Comment: Thank you mate!! I applied what was in the official docs alongside my original mapping, and so far it's working like a charm.